# Get public string in codebehind into LayoutTemplate of ListView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview

A doubt in ASP.NET(VB)

I have a public variable in code-behind(ASPX.VB)

```
Public _orderCode As String = "Hello World"
```

At ASPX, I would like to access it inline. 
That too inside the LayoutTemplate of a ListView

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listView_OrderReplies" 
                DataKeyNames="ProductID"
                DataSourceID="sdsProducts">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <h1>Order Replies for Order Code  = <%# _orderCode %></h1>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <b>Name</b>:  <%#Eval("ProductName")%><br />
        <b>Stock</b>:  <%#Eval("UnitsInStock")%><br />
        <b>Price</b>:  <%#Eval("UnitPrice")%> <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

That is, I want this inline binding to succeed

```
<h1>Order Replies for Order Code  = <%# _orderCode %></h1>
```

or

```
<h1>Order Replies for Order Code  = <%= _orderCode %></h1>
```

I know it will work inside the page if its not inside a databound control.
What I need is a way to access the variable using inline code blocks.

Is it possible?
Can anybody point me in the right direction?

BTW, I know to bind it in code-behind and all.
I am looking for a specific solution if there is one and a confirmation if there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be done or at least I doubt it. My advise, use a literal control or label and assign the text at code-behind.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452928/asp-net-inline-code) .
Darko's answer was:
Inline code is executed when the page is being rendered ie. after the Page_PreRender event and before the Unload event. Hence after databinding, your inline code is probably a 'goner' for it to work.

Comment: for a real solution have a look at my answer

Comment: Can confirm that Nikola's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 10):

It **can** be done, and quite easily at that. Just handle `OnLayoutCreated` event, and in it call `DataBind()` method on `LayoutTemplate` control (all child controls will automatically databind as well).

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" OnLayoutCreated="lv_LayoutCreated">...</asp:ListView>

protected void lv_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lv.Controls[0].DataBind();
}
```

Just make sure that whatever data is being databound there, it is instantiated before that (on postbacks as well).

Or you can find a specific control in it, and databind just that: `lv.Controls[0].FindControl("id").DataBind();`

And if you want it databound only on `ListView` databinding, than do it in `OnDataBound` event - but you **must** target a control which doesn't contain `itemPlaceholder`, or your `ItemTemplate` will databind again (with no data this time):

```
protected void lv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lv.Controls.Count > 0)
        lv.Controls[0].FindControl("head").DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I had been searching for an answer to this for hours.  Your solution is simple, elegant, and most importantly works!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Right when I was beginning to think accessing an element within a list view's layout template was impossible.. You, my friend, saved the day.

Comment: Perfect. You're my hero. This should be marked as the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is also addressed here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LayoutTemplate_DataBind.aspx

and here:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1201992/3319344.aspx#3319344

The solutions provided here are to extend or adapt the ListView control and properly handle the data-binding of the LayoutTemplate.