# Why can not use <%=...%> in the ListView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

All, Generally .If we want to output a variable in a page which defined in the code-behind class file of page . We could set the variable with `public` or `protect` visibility. and in the front page we can use it like below.
`<%=VariableName%>`.

But I don't know why can't use it in the ListView. Please help to review my code.

In the front page

```
<div id="divIssuedListContainer" class="myIssuedList">
<asp:ListView id="listShower" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="divIssuedListHeadTitle">
            <div id="divIssuedListTitleIco">
                <img alt="" src="ico/IssuedCap.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="divIssuedListTitleName">
                <span>ISSUED</span><span>TRADE NAMES</span><span>/LICENSES</span>
            </div>
            <div id="divIssuedListItemNumber">
                <span>
                    <%=iListNumber%></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="divIssuedListBody">
            <ul>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img alt="" src="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <%# Eval("altID") %>
                                -
                                <%# Eval("englishTradeName") %></span></div>
                        <div>
                            <span>Expired Date:<%# Eval("expDate") %></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In the code-behind of page

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected int iListNumber = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<SimpleCapModel> DataSourceList = TestDataHelper.GetMyIssuedList();
            listShower.DataSource = DataSourceList;
            iListNumber = DataSourceList.Count();
            listShower.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I got an error page said :

```
 The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Source Error:


Line 19:             listShower.DataSource = DataSourceList;
Line 20:             iListNumber = DataSourceList.Count();
Line 21:             listShower.DataBind();//this line cause error.
Line 22:         }
Line 23:     }
```

And If I use the expression `<%#iListNumber%>`. The error is gone, but I got a empty value instead of the number of the list. please review below rendered result html :

```
<div id="divIssuedListItemNumber">
<span> </span>
</div>
```

I didn't know whether I missed something ? If I did .Please help to let me know it.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<%#iListNumber %>` because you are using data-binding the ListView, otherwise you'll get the exception (see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112 for more on inline expressions).

Try using `<%#iListNumber.ToString %>` and see if that makes a difference.

**UPDATE**:

The problem appears to be that your inline-expression is in the `LayoutTemplate`, where data-binding [apparently] won't work without [either handling the `OnLayoutCreated` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581515/get-public-string-in-codebehind-into-layouttemplate-of-listview#answer-9844662), or extending the `ListView`.

See either of the following for examples of how to extend the `ListView`:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42962/Databind-Expression-in-ListView-LayoutTemplate
- http://forums.asp.net/p/1201992/3319344.aspx#3319344

Comment: +1 very helpful post. But `<%#iListNumber.ToString()%>` doesn't work.

Comment: *doesn't work* how?  Still giving you an exception?  Not giving you the value that you want?

Comment: Sorry, Without any exception, Not show the number of the list. thanks.

Comment: @pete Yes, Right, I also found it is because the expression is in the ListView. But not found the solution until you tell me. very good !thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error you're receiving, it basically means this: you can't just randomly throw .NET tags in databound controls.

The solution is to, instead, throw that random text in a .NET control, like this: `<asp:Literal Runat="server" Text="<%# iListNumber %>" />`

When you put a .NET codeblock in code, it dynamically has to build a control placeholder for it.  It's a little tricky.  But if you wrap all your custom tags up in a control, then just that one property gets databound and the databound block remains "clean" if that makes sense.

Comment: is it showing 0?  Should it be incrementing for each item in the list?  What is the expectation of that value?

Comment: It shows empty, the render html is `<div id="divIssuedListItemNumber">
    <span> </span>
    </div>`. it supposed be the number of the list (in my case is 10.) or 0. thanks.