# how use If Statement in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have on ListView

```
<asp:ListView ID="MyListView" runat="server">
      <LayoutTemplate>
       <ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="/"><i></i>home</a></li>
  <li runat="server" />
  <li class="myClass">
    <a title="SomeTitle" href="example.com/default.aspx">
    </a>
 </li>
     </ul>
        <ascx:Menu runat="server" Visible="true" />
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
     <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>' 
                                           Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'/></li>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <li class="active">
     <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>' 
                                          Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'  /></li>
      </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

on .cs file I have one string

`protected string CurrentName = MyMethod();`//that return a string or null

in aspx page I want to show in `<LayoutTemplate>` different structure of tags in dependecy of my CurrentName
I try like this:

```
<% if(this.CurrentName ==null){ %>
<ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/"><i></i>home</a></li>
      <li runat="server" />
      <li class="myClass">
        <a title="SomeTitle" href="example.com/default.aspx">
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <ascx:Menu runat="server" Visible="true" />
<% } else {  %>

<ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/"><i></i>home</a></li>
      <li class="myClass">
        <ascx:Menu runat="server" Visible="true" />
     </li>
  </ul>
<% }  %>
```

this method not work, how use IF statements in ASPX page right?

Comment: could you please post the cs code? thank you in advance !

Comment: @Christos  protected string CurrentName = MyMethod();
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {}

Comment: I think that your problem may be in the way you assign the value to the CurrentName. When you do the assignment etc.

Comment: @Alex : I think just change this line - **<% if(this.CurrentName ==null){ %>** to this - **<% if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CurrentName)){ %>**. Just check and let us know...

Comment: @KrishnrajRana if I use like this, in browser is show this error: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: @Alex : check this link - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909037/why-can-not-use-in-the-listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909037/why-can-not-use-in-the-listview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement this with two panels which have exlusive conditions on `Visible` attribute, so that only one of them is rendered at a single load:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%# this.CurrentName == null %>'>
  <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/"><i></i>home</a></li>
      <li runat="server" />
      <li class="myClass">
        <a title="SomeTitle" href="example.com/default.aspx">
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <ascx:Menu runat="server" Visible="true" /> 
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%# this.CurrentName != null %>'>
  <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/"><i></i>home</a></li>
      <li class="myClass">
        <ascx:Menu runat="server" Visible="true" />
     </li>
  </ul>
</asp:Panel>
```